# Prove equation in probability theory

Tags: probability

I have this equation:
$$
P((A \bar{B}) \cup C) = P(\bar{A}B) + P(C) - P(BC) + P(ABC)
$$
I need to prove that. I tried using already existing formulas and equations but I can't figure out how to reach this equation.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Question with same theme: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3620997/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P((A\overline{B})\cup C)=P(A\overline{B})+P(C)-P(A\overline{B}C)$ so you are really proving 
$$
P(A\overline{B})-P(A\overline{B}C)=P(\overline{A}B)+P(ABC)-P(BC).
$$
The way to go is in the equation above, all probability terms that are the intersection of two events can be turned into the intersection of 3 events. The advantage of viewing it this way is that all terms are disjoint. For example, $P(A\overline{B})=P(A\overline{B}C)+P(A\overline{B}\overline{C})$. The equation then reads
\begin{align}
P(A\overline{B}C)+P(A\overline{B}\overline{C})-P(A\overline{B}C)&=P(\overline{A}BC)+P(\overline{A}B\overline{C})\\
&+P(ABC)-(P(ABC)+P(\overline{A}BC)) \\
&=P(\overline{A}B\overline{C})
\end{align}
so
$$
P(A\overline{B}\overline{C})=P(\overline{A}B\overline{C}).
$$
Are you sure there isn't more information or a typo? The proof is to work backwards in steps. In my way, I assumed what I was trying to prove, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Here's a counter-example. Let our samples space be the space of outcomes for the roll of a fair dice. Let $ A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}, C = \{2, 3\} $.

Then, the left side evaluates to 
$$ P((A\bar{B}) \cup C) = P(\{1\} \cup \{2, 3\}) = 1/2. $$ 
On the other hand, the right side evaluates to
$$
\begin{align*}
& P(\bar{A}B) + P(C) - P(BC) + P(ABC) = \\
& P(\{4, 5, 6\}) + P(\{2, 3\}) - P(\{2, 3\}) + P(\{2, 3\}) = \\
& 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/3 + 1/3 = 5/6. 
\end{align*}
$$

Note that I generated this example by finding a set of events in which $ P(A\bar{B}\bar{C}) = P(\bar{A}B\bar{C}) $ following from the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for your example, it is clear for me now.